# Security & Pyscript

Tags: python, security, pyscript

I am coding a Python editor, which can execute python codes and returns the output. My initial idea was to code a backend service for it, that will run the Python script and return the output. However with the release of Pyscript, I am wondering if I can do it in the frontend.

One of my biggest concerns is the security, since the Python editor may need to connect AWS resources (such as Databases, Dynamodb, RDS...). Will using credentials to connect AWS resources be a security concern? As I see, Pyscript is also obfuscating the Python code, thus I am a bit confused.

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However with the release of Pyscript, I am wondering if I can do it in
> the frontend.

Yes. There are examples on the Internet. This repository has an example of repl in the browser:

https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/tree/main/pyscriptjs/examples

> One of my biggest concerns is the security, since the Python editor
> may need to connect AWS resources (such as Databases, Dynamodb,
> RDS...). Will using credentials to connect AWS resources be a security
> concern?

This is a very big concern. Pyscript will expose your credentials in the Python code that is easily readable from the Browser debug window or by simply using a CLI such as `curl` or `wget` to download your HTML.

> As I see, Pyscript is also obfuscating the Python code, thus I am a
> bit confused.

I am not sure what obfuscating you have seen, but you cannot hide anything from the browser or tools that can download your HTML and Python files. This will not improve your security as you have zero source code security with Pyscript.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: see John Hanley's comment below explaining why my idea wouldn't work.*

---

Couldn't you put the credentials in a text file on server in a folder inaccessible to the public? Then inside the `<py-script>` tags, run:

```
with open("../../secure_directory/my_secrets.txt") as f:
    my_secrets = f.read()
```

Would this provide some marginally improved level of security?

Comment: In order for Pyscript to run your example, the server file **my_secrets.txt** must be readable by Python running in the browser. That also means the user can also read the secrets in the browser. Once a secret is downloaded, it is **not** secure. On top of that, JavaScript can also access the file **my_secrets.txt**, making it very easy to grab that secret.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using py-env tag, but <py-script src=" doesn't work to manage the file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).